# accepts_nested_attributes_for with hidden_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Been searching stackoverflow for an answer to this one all day. I have a form to create a new topic. The first post should also be created with the topic. All is well except user_id is not being saved to the post.

**Post Model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Topic Model**

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :forum
  belongs_to :user  
  has_many :posts 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
end
```

**Post Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to topic_path(@post.topic_id)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:content, :topic_id, :topic_name, :user_id)
  end
```

end

**Topic Controller**

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @topic = Topic.new
    @topic.posts.build
  end

  def create
    @topic = Topic.new(topic_params)
    if @topic.save
      redirect_to @topic
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def topic_params
    params.require(:topic).permit(
      :topic_name, 
      :forum_id, 
      :user_id,  
      posts_attributes: [:id, :content, :topic_id, :topic_name, :user_id ] )
  end
end
```

**new/topic View**

```
<%= form_for(@topic) do |f| %> 
   <%= f.hidden_field :forum_id, :value => params[:forum_id] %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
   <%= f.label :topic_name %>
   <%= f.text_field :topic_name %>
   <%= f.fields_for :posts do |p| %>
     <%= p.label :content %>
     <%= p.text_area :content %>
   <% end %>

   <%= f.submit "Post Topic", class: "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

I am not entirely sure why the user_id is not being passed to the post. Hopefully someone smarter than me can help me learn what to do :)

**UPDATE**

I changed the strong params in my topics controller to this.

```
def topic_params
  params.require(:topic).permit(
  :topic_name, 
  :forum_id, 
posts_attributes: [:content, :topic_id, :id, '_destroy' ] ).merge(:user_id => current_user.id, posts_attributes: [:user_id => current_user.id]) 
    end
```

Now the user_id is working but none of the posts_attributes like :content are being saved. I'm having a lot of fun with this one..

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, `user_id` is not in the `posts_attributes` since the only attributes there is `content`, which means that allowing other attributes like `topic_id` and `topic_name` is useless.

Now that we cleared that, you SHOULD NOT use a form input for the value of the creator of any model, because it's easy for anyone to tamper with the form and set the value to anything else, like other user's id. Alternatively, you should set the `user_id` value in the controller, in your case, the TopicsController. Here is the code:

```
def create
  _params = topic_params.deep_merge(user: current_user, posts_attributes: {user: current_user})
  @topic = Topic.new(_params)
  if @topic.save
    redirect_to @topic
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

and remove the `user_id` hidden field from the form.

**UPDATE:** Your last code update contains an error; it should be `.merge(:user_id => current_user.id, posts_attributes: {:user_id => current_user.id})`. You used a square brackets around `:user_id => current_user.id` instead of curly ones.

Comment: I didn't realize that I shouldn't be using the hidden_field. I used your code and get the error undefined method `with_indifferent_access' for #<User:0x5ef0c80>'. Time to search SO some more. I think I am on the right track now.

Comment: That gives me the error no implicit conversion of String into Integer. Back to searching SO.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the form attributes that being generated in the browser, all the nested attributes for post have a prefix like `topic[post_attributes]`, try change the form to:

```
<%= form_for(@topic) do |f| %> 
   <%= f.hidden_field :forum_id, :value => params[:forum_id] %>
   <%= f.label :topic_name %>
   <%= f.text_field :topic_name %>
   <%= f.fields_for :posts do |p| %>
     <%= p.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
     <%= p.label :content %>
     <%= p.text_area :content %>
   <% end %>

   <%= f.submit "Post Topic", class: "btn btn-large btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried this before it still doesn't include the user_id.